# simplest way to collect user input using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to move to using SharePoint and move away from sending an email with an excel file listing an inventory of applications to development teams and asking each team to edit the attached excel file to note what rows (application names) are impacted in their development with either regression, development, or no impact then send me back the edited file. I don't want to reconcile each into a master file.

in what way can I create a form for all my users to just enter and submit their respective information and have SharePoint compile the results into a spreadsheet for me?

today, what I do is list all the applications in inventory in an excel file with fields such as application name, appId, appOwner, appDescription... and include an empty first column for users to add the appropritate word ("regression", "development", or "no impact") to the records as needed. I would love to replace this manual process with SharePoint automating this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can import that excel file into SharePoint list, and let the user modify data in SharePoint list to specify status of application. Applications will be rows of data in List and Application name, status, etc. will be columns in the list.